# Multi-media files not showing

Tags: 8, files, media

Uploaded `multi-media` files to:

```
public_html/sites/default/files
```

- no error messages
- permissions: 0775
- files do not appear (in Content, as do files uploaded through the media editor)

Switching from **Wordpress** to **Drupal**.  New to Drupal.  Not a programmer.  It would take a long time to upload 1,000+ files through a media editor.  How do I get Drupal to see these files without uploading them one-by-one?

Comment: Hi Catherine, could you clear up what you mean up getting Drupal to "see" the files? Uploading files to a folder won't do anything to make Drupal aware of them (unless of course the paths to those files are already referenced in the CMS somehow, file field, ckeditor reference, etc; are they?) If you can provide some context, even a brief outline of the steps you've taken to get where you are, it'll make it much easier for people to understand what you need, and hopefully give you a decent answer.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I don't know what a CMS is.  

With Wordpress, I uploaded 8GB of over 1,000 mixed media files which immediately became publicly accessible.  Took a few days, but it was all automatically identified and organized through the file uploader.

To leave Wordpress behind, I need Drupal to do the same.

My host tech support helped SFTP files to the right place.  According to Content in Drupal, that is:  public_html/sites/default/files with file permissions 0775.  I don't know what the next step is.  Not a programmer/developer and unable to find more useful documentation.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/about/media-kit/drupal-8

"versatile, structured content"

Powerful, built-in integration tools to connect Drupal to other software in an organization’s infrastructure
    Easier content creation, using responsively designed interfaces
    Renewed mobile-first focus, so people can create sites and applications that work on more modern devices than ever
    All-new configuration management for safer and faster site development and maintenance
    Improved built-in multilingual support, with the ability to translate any component of the software

Comment: https://drupalsquad.com/blog/drupal-8-media-handling-easy-enough-kittens

Drupal 8 finally includes a media “library” out of the box, that gives content editors some control over the files (images, documents, videos, etc) uploaded to Drupal. There is a Files dashboard now in the Content section of Drupal’s admin UI where you can see uploaded files and content entities where these files are used. There is finally out of the box integration of WYSIWYG and image insertion – you don’t need to install extra modules to be able to upload an image while editing article text.

Comment: Sounds like Wordpress has a feature that scans for new files on a scheduled job and adds them to the library - Drupal doesn't have such a feature out of the box; there may well be a contributed module which provides that functionality (though I couldn't find one quickly on Google), but as Berdir mentions in his answer a lot of those modules haven't been ported over to Drupal 8 yet, it's still very young

Comment: CMS = Content Management System by the way, broadly speaking that's what Drupal is and what Wordpress is becoming/has become

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Drupal about your files *somehow*.

You could write a script yourself.

Another approach would be to use the archive upload of [File entity](https://github.com/drupal-media/file_entity), but you won't be able to upload hundreds of them in a single archive either, the file will simply get too big.

Maybe there is also a module for this, but it's likely not available yet for Drupal 8.

Comment: I am not a programmer.  I was told Drupal is for ordinary website builders, not just developers.  I have no idea how to write a script.  I have no way of hiring a programmer.

Comment: @Catherine Use media module or multiupload. You can upload your files in bulk. I would suggest to use Drupal 7 as 8 is not matured yet and you will not find some modules here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Unfortunately Drupal 8 is already set up.  Wish I had not.  Too late to cry about it now though.  Wish all the hooplah about Drupal 8 had been more honest.

Comment: Drupal 8 came out just over a month ago. Drupal core can't support every use case, and yours isn't. Many contrib modules aren't ready yet, that is changing fast. There are modules like https://www.drupal.org/project/image_importer, but someone will have to spend time on converting it to Drupal 8. There's also https://www.drupal.org/project/dropzonejs, but it doesn't yet have standalone page to upload images, you'd need to set up an entity browser first.

Answer (score 0):

What works for now:

1. created a new content type named 'Media' and set upload to unlimited
2. added file field (could not change body because data has already been added elsewhere)
3. created a page
4. selected multiple files using the new 'Media' content type (not the
   CK Editor media uploader which only handles a single file per
   upload)
5. edited URL to reflect name of media page

Note 1:  Did not see a place to include all displays, but that seems to be the default.

Note 2:  128MB is the default limit for uploads in my Drupal 8 install.  Not optimal since there are 1,000+ files to upload, and not happy given Drupal's grand claims about media handling.  But it is working though.

Note 3:  Update.  Host was kind enough to increase the max file upload in PHP to 256 so I am able to upload more files with each upload.  Did need to reorganize folders and certain files offline first with naming conventions that will present a respectable order on the site.  During the past several hours I was able to upload nearly half the files.  Fair enough for half a day's work and a better than expected outcome.

Comment: No idea where you've read about "grand claims about media handling", but media handling is one of the things that Drupal 8 does *not* do well at the moment. Unfortunate, but actively being worked on by the Drupal Media team.

Comment: I posted a couple of links to articles(?) above.  Not being a developer, programmer or a business with resources that can afford either, I researched as much as I could before choosing Drupal.  I found a lot of recommendations for Drupal 8 because it has been said many times it is competing with Wordpress, which I am trying leaving behind.

No worries though.  It'll take awhile to get all these files uploaded, but it is working.  And at least once they're up, they can be left where they are.

Except for file management, I like Drupal 8 or I wouldn't stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Flysystem](https://www.drupal.org/project/flysystem) and [Filefield_sources_flysystem](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/arit_nath/2604164).

With this approach, you can just place your files on Dropbox, Amazon S3, some FTP folder, etc. and the magic of Flysystem will enable you to attach them to file fields in Drupal and serve them to your site's visitors.

Filefield_sources_flysystem helps by enabling you to "pick" an individual file from your files folder (even if that's e.g. Dropbox) when editing a content item's file field in Drupal.

Batch processing 1000 files is still a little tricky, as the UI for associating files with Drupal content is always set up to do 1 (or at least a few) at a time. Migration is the best way of handling this that I know of. You can define a spreadsheet listing all the Drupal entities you wish to exist on a separate row each, specify the filenames or paths for each row, create a YAML file to that tells the Migrate module how to understand that spreadsheet, upload that migration file and trigger it. Not easy, but not hard core coding either.